# How to keep a sidebar item selected when navigation link is triggered in the detail view on iPadOS with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, ipados

I'm asking your help today about a mystery behavior of the navigation link coupled with the sidebar on iPadOS.

First, here is my sidebar code:

```
NavigationView {
    List(1..<5) { _ in
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
            Label("Item", systemImage: "house")
        }
    }
    .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
}
```

This view contains navigation links to display a detail view as you can see.

My detail view contains another navigation link to a simple view containing a Text. Nothing more.

Here is the code of my detail view:

```
VStack {
    Spacer()
        
    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello")) {
        Text("Touch me")
    }
        
    Spacer()
}
```

So far, so good. Now, let's compile  this code and see what's going on:

[image: sidebar]

Great ! The sidebar is well displayed and the first item is selected. Now let's touching the **Touch me** button on the detail view to trigger a navigation link inside the detail view.

[image: sidebar item unselected]

Oh no... When touching the button, the navigation link is triggered as wanted, but the item in the sidebar become unselected. Is there something I'm doing wrong ? I also tried to use the selection binding in the list but it doesn't change anything.
To compare, I would like to reproduce the iPad **Music** app navigation of the **Album** item of the sidebar. In there, you can select an album and go deeper in the navigation stack. And it keeps the sidebar item selected !

Can you help me to fix this issue ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63230898/7129318) answer your question?

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I can't believe that Apple is doing it that way. For information, this behavior seems to appears in iOS 15 but not on iOS 14... Weird.

Comment: This issue only on iOS15, I test it on iOS14 and iOS16 it work fine!, @Yrb this answer fix the issue on iOS15 and make it behave as iOS14 and iOS16