# How do I start my SwiftUI app in a children view?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

Okay, here's what my app looks like.
[image: View Hierachy]

```swift
@main
struct MemorizableApp: App {
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()                             // Configure the FirebaseApp instance
        Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true     // Set DB persistence to true
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
                SignInView()
                    .onOpenURL{ url in
                        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)
                    }
            } else {
                MainView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is `MemorizableApp.swift`. As you can see, the app starts in MainView. But I want the app to launch in NotebooksView instead. Obviously, changing MainView to NotebooksView in the code above won't work because 1) NotebooksView doesn't have a NavigationView in it, and 2) I won't be able to navigate back to MainView. But somehow Apple's Shortcuts app did exactly this without creating a custom back button. How can I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Make NavigationLink in MainView with tags and activate needed one in onAppear. Here is an example of similar use-case https://stackoverflow.com/a/63230898/12299030.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is activate your `NavigationLink` programmatically:

In `MainView` add: `@State var shouldNavigate = false`, then modify your `NavigationLink` to the following:

```
NavigationLink(destination: NoteBooksView(), isActive: $shouldNavigate) {
    ...
}
```

And in `MemorizableApp`:

```
@main
struct MemorizableApp: App {
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()                             // Configure the FirebaseApp instance
        Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true     // Set DB persistence to true
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
                SignInView()
                    .onOpenURL{ url in
                        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)
                    }
            } else {
                MainView(shouldNavigate: true) //set it to true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The use of `NavigationLink(destination: Content, isActive: Binding<Bool>)` & `NavigationView` is **deprecated** in `iOS 16`. Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink) & [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack/).